# Crear DOM con jquery y comprobar existencia

Tags: javascript, jquery

He creado una funcion que realiza una consulta ajax con retorno de datos en json, cuando esta funcion recibe los datos, comprueba si el DOM existe, si no existe lo crea.

La duda es: Cuando el DOM existe en vez de crearlo debe cambiar los datos dentro de ese DOM.

Ejemplo:

```
function getInfo(clas, div, ty) {
    $.get('MI ARCHIVO PHP?t=' + ty, function(data){
        if($(div).length == 0) {
            clas.append('<div class="' + div + '">' + data.text + '</div>');
        }else{
            $(div).html(data.text);
        }
    }, 'json');
}
```

La cosa es que, la primera vez funciona perfectamente, me crea el div con la informacion correcta, pero la segundacuando llamo la funcion con un setInterval en vez de cambiarme la informacion dentro del div, lo que hace es repertirmela constantemente, osea, que en la pantalla acabo con un monton de div con la misma clase.

Las variables de la funcion son: getInfo($('.infobox'), '.info', 0);
La primera hace referencia a un div que ya viene dentro del archivo html, la segunda es la clase del div que tiene que crear o modificar y la tercera a una parte del archivo php en el ajax. Debo decir que el "infobox' contiene varias cajas div de informacion, y siempre me las repite.

Que estoy haciendo mal??

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿ Podrías colocar el código exacto que usas con `setInterval( )` ? Podría ser relevante para la pregunta / respuesta.

Comment: Hola @Trauma, dentro del setInterval() va incluida la funcion creada, el setInterval esta establecido para que llame a la funcion cada 5 segundos.

Answer (score 1):

Dandole vueltas, he conseguido averiguar cual era el problema.
Resuta que en la segunda variable de la funcion, la clase '.info' la ponia con el '.' cuando deberia ser sin el punto.

Las variables originales eran getInfo($('.infobox'), '.info', 0) cuando deberia ser getInfo($('.infobox'), 'info', 0).

La razon de esto es porque en la funcion a la hora de añadir el DOM a la variable clas 'clas.append('')' esa variable 'div' tenia el '.', por lo que javascript no la reconocia.
La solucion fue quitar el punto y añadirselo a la funcion a la hora de buscar el DOM.

$('.' + div).length == 0 aqui ya si que lo encontraba perfectamente.